# Cycle consists of projects in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have project A and project B in eclipse.
Project A is reference to B while B is reference to A. So I add Project B to the "Java Build Path >> Project" of A. I also add Project A to the "Java Build Path >> Project" of B.

So the thing is when I try to build the project, it came up with an warning said "A cycle was detected in the build path of project 'A'. The cycle consists of projects {A, B}". I want to run the project in mobile. When I run as "android application" link with Sumsung Galaxy S3, it just keep loading and finally get error said "stack over flow".

How can I solve this problem? Is it relate to the warning about the cycle consists? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as the error clearly says, you have a cyclic dependency. That is poor architecture. You have to remove that dependency. Since I do not know the details of the dependency, I can suggest general possible solutions -

1. Can you merge the two projects and have just one project?
2. Can you create a separate library project "Project C"? Such that "Project A" and "Project B" depend on "Project C". But there is either no dependency between "Project A" and "Project B" or only "Project A" depends of "Project B" but not the other way round.
   [image]